# Select all entities of exact class, but not derived from it using NHibernate Criteria API

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two classes: `Cat` and `DomesticCat`, that extends `Cat`.

I want to select all `Cat`s, but no one`DomesticCat`. How to do it using NHibernate criteria API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var nonDomesticCats = session.CreateCriteria<Cat>()
                             .Add(Restrictions.Eq("class", typeof(Cat)))
                             .List<Cat>();
```

`class` is a pseudo-property that represents the concrete type of entities in a class hierarchy.

It can be used transparently with any inheritance strategy except implicit.

Comment: A class name embedded in the `where` clause will be **translated to its discriminator value** - says Hibernate documentation.

Comment: It's translated to a discriminator value when using table-per-clas-hierarchy, and to the corresponding internal case-statement values when using table-per-class or table-per-concrete-class.

Answer (score 0):

well it depends on the implementation.

If for example, you have a discriminator column (lets say `<discriminator column="CatType" type="string"/>` and the `DomesticCat` inheritor class discriminates with value `"domestic"`) you could make an query like this

```
var allCatsButDomestic = nhSes.CreateQuery("from Cat c where c.CatType <> :catType")
     .SetString("catType", "domestic")
     .List<Cat>();
```

(in this particular example the Cat abstract class also maps the CatType column to a CatType string property)

EDIT and in Criteria form

```
var nonDomesticCats = session.CreateCriteria<Cat>()
                             .Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("CatType", "domestic")))
                             .List<Cat>();
```

your comment about AnotherCat again implies that there is some way of discriminating between entities at the db level.

Comment: This is HQL, and it strictly depends on hierarchy. And what about if `AnotherCat` is derived from `DomesticCat`. I need to select only `Cat`s, your query says: select all, except `DomesticCat`.